# Bash: How to escape minus in `if [ ... ` (alias "test")?

Tags: scripting, kill, test

I need to test this:

```
kill -0 $LAST_PID;
```

So I wrote

```
if [ kill -0 $LAST_PID ] ; then ...
```

But this results in an error - `unknown operator after -` or so.

how do I escape the options within `if`?

Comment: Not sure why it's downvoted but since it is, it's probably a bad question and needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `if` that you're trying to escape it from, it's `test` / `[`. But you aren't testing the executing of `kill` that way; you're testing strings. You want:

```
if kill -0 "$LAST_PID"; then ...
```

*that* will test `kill`'s return code.